# What is the answer to this rebus puzzle "IM IM"

Tags: rebus

The answer is related to drugs and we cannot seem to solve it. It is simply

IM IM

Comment: +1, and welcome to Puzzling.SE! I have also voted to keep this question open. The reasons for voting to close were {1}"Unclear what you're asking," but it seems clear to me. "This is a Rebus. The  clue is 'IM IM.' " A perfectly logical answer has been given and up-voted. {2}"Looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere." This appears to be a case of "My friend came up with this rebus and I can't figure it out." I highly doubt this came from a source that is worried about attribution or copyright infringement.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely it's

> Impaired

as in "Even though it's now legal to smoke cannabis in Canada, you [aren't allowed to drive impaired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFKaF.jpg)".

Comment: +1 for the cultural reference!

Comment: Not as good as this (doesn't really work with two IMs) but alternative is: I'm spaced out